# How to create the lambda char in OCaml?

Tags: utf-8, ocaml

I would like to create a function in OCaml that returns the char lambda (UTF8 0x03bb) but I can't use `Char.chr` because it's not in the ASCII chart. Is there a way to do so? I am new to OCaml...

Answer (score 5):

First note that you are mixing [scalar values](http://unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value) (an integer in the ranges 0..0xD7FF and 0xE000 .. 0x10FFFF) and their encoding (the byte serialization of such an integer). Don't say UTF-8 0x03bb, as it doesn't make any sense, what you are talking about is the scalar value U+03BB, the integer that represent small lambda in Unicode.

Now as you noticed the OCaml `char` type can't represent such integers as it is limited to 256 values. What you can do however is to represent their UTF-8 *encoding* in OCaml strings which are (or more precisely became) sequences of arbitrary bytes. For U+03BB its UTF-8 serialization is the byte sequence `0xCE` `0xBB` so you can write:

```
let lambda = "\xCE\xBB"
```

If you prefer to deal with scalar values directly you can use an UTF-8 encoder like [`Uutf`](http://erratique.ch/software/uutf) (disclaimer I'm the author) and do for example:

```
let lambda = 0x03BB
let lambda_utf_8 =
   let b = Buffer.create 5 in
   Uutf.Buffer.add_utf_8 b lambda; Buffer.contents b
```

For a short refresher on Unicode and a few biased tips on how to deal with Unicode in OCaml you can consult this [minimal Unicode introduction](http://erratique.ch/software/uucp/doc/Uucp.html#uminimal).

**UPDATE**

Since OCaml 4.06, unicode escapes are supported in literal strings. The following UTF-8 encodes the lambda character in the `lambda` string:

```
let lambda = "\u{03BB}"
```

Comment: Note that if your source files are encoded as UTF-8, which seems fairly common, you can also do `let lambda = "λ"`.

Comment: Yes however you need to be careful with that: the OCaml compiler formally sees only a sequence of bytes which means that such a string is not checked for UTF-8 validity and may be subject to bugs in the UTF-8 encoder of your *editor*. Using escapes heres guarantees that you will have the right byte sequence at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just tagging along after the excellent answer by Daniel,

If you just want that 0x03bb, you can do

```
#require "camomile"
open CamomileLibrary.UChar

let () = 
  let c = of_int 955 in
  (* Just to do something with it *)
  print_endline (CamomileLibrary.UPervasives.escaped_uchar c)
```

Here's a way to actually "see" it on the terminal.

```
#require "camomile, zed"

open CamomileLibrary.UChar

let () =
  Zed_utf8.make 1 (of_int 955) |> print_endline
```

and I got the decimal of 955 from: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03bb/index.htm